# An error with a ternary operator

Tags: java

In the following code:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> leavesCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public void addLeaf(int leaf, int count){
    leavesCount.containsKey(leaf) ? leavesCount.put(leaf, leavesCount.get(leaf) + count) : leavesCount.put(leaf, count);
}
```

I get the following error with `leaf` inside the `containsKey`:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean
```

Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: You are not assigning the result to anything.

Comment: You have to use an `if` statement, the ternary operator is only for use as an expression.

Comment: Are you sure you get this error on this code? Your code should produce different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it to

```
leavesCount.put(leaf, leavesCount.containsKey(leaf) ? (leavesCount.get(leaf) + count) : count)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how ternary operations work. To use a ternary for this you would want to change the function to

```
public void addLeaf(int leaf, int count){
    leavesCount.put( leaf, leavesCount.containsKey(leaf) ? leavesCount.get(leaf) + count : count)
}
```

Which isn't really best practice. You are better off using an if statement.

```
public void addLeaf(int leaf, int count){
    if(leavesCount.containsKey(leaf)){
        leavesCount.put(leaf, leavesCount.get(leaf) + count);
    }else{
        leavesCount.put(leaf, count);
    }
}
```

The reason for this is readability. Putting a ternary inside of a function calls can start to get messy.

You could also move it to a var.

```
public void addLeaf(int leaf, int count){
    count = leavesCount.containsKey(leaf) ? leavesCount.get(leaf) + count : count;
    leavesCount.put( leaf, count)
}
```

Comment: That second recommendation got you my up-vote. This isn't the place for use of ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, there's an elegant built-in method to do what you want:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> leavesCount = new HashMap<>();

public void addLeaf(int leaf, int count) {
    leavesCount.merge(leaf, count, Integer::sum);
}
```

This uses [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, which expects the key and the value, along with a *merge function* that merges the old value with the new value if the key was already present in the map.

For the merge function, I'm using `Integer::sum`, which is a method reference to the `Integer.sum` method. This method reference acts like a [`BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html), i.e. it expects two values and returns their sum.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `leavesCount.containsKey(leaf) ? leavesCount.put(leaf, leavesCount.get(leaf) + count) : leavesCount.put(leaf, count);` with

```
    if (leavesCount.containsKey(leaf)) {
        leavesCount.put(leaf, leavesCount.get(leaf) + count);
    } else {
        leavesCount.put(leaf, count);
    }
```